# npm Workspaces linking "dist" directory

Tags: angular, npm, monorepo, workspace, lerna

Simplyfied I've got the following project structure:

```
workspace/
├─ package.json                  <-- With npm workspaces (see below)
├─ packages/
│  ├─ angular/                   <-- Angular Workspace
│  │  ├─ projects/
│  │  │  ├─ a/                   <-- Angular Library A Source
│  │  │  │  ├─ package.json
│  │  │  ├─ b/                   <-- Angular Library B Source
│  │  │  │  ├─ package.json
│  │  ├─ dist/
│  │  │  ├─ a/                   <-- Built Angular Library A
│  │  │  ├─ b/                   <-- Built Angular Library B
│  ├─ webcomponents/             <-- Stencil.js Webcomponents
│  │  ├─ package.json
│  │  ├─ dist/
│  ├─ demo-app/                  <-- This package depends on all of the above
|  │  ├─ package.json/
```

In the root `package.json` I've got the following workspaces config:

```json
"workspaces": [
  "packages/*",
  "packages/angular/projects/*"
]
```

Installing the dependencies of all workspaces works fine and as expected. But when it comes to linking the packages locally in my `demo-app` it works only for `webcomponents` since the  `dist` folder is directly inside the configured workspace.

For the Angular Libraries however, the source folders `projects/[a,b]` are linked instead of the `dist` folders... Which leads to build errors in the `demo-app` package of course.

We used to use *Lerna* to manage our packages and it followed the `publishConfig.directory` configuration in the `package.json` file for linking. However, npm workspaces seem to work differently... I've read the whole (very short) docs about workspaces and couldn't find any configuration option for `dist` folders which are not part of the actual workspace.

Changing the workspaces config to point to the `dist` instead of the source folders solves the issue for linking:

```json
"workspaces": [
  "packages/*",
  "packages/angular/dist/*"
]
```

But it breaks automatic versioning of the actual source `package.json` with *Lerna*. So this cannot be the solution.

Does anybody know how I need to configure this setup correctly? Is it even possible?

Comment: Lerna probably knows about Angular workspaces but npm does not. Normally, you specify the package entry point using the `main` field in `package.json`. I do not known if this can be outside the directory containing `package.json`.

Comment: You could drop Angular workspaces and only use npm workspaces. You would have to move both Angular projects to their own, separate Angular project directly under `packages`.

Comment: Hi @rveerd, I actually wanted to avoid this... I don't think that this would work either, since Angular is creating a new package.json in the dist Folder. This is really meant to be the complete package content so I need to find a way that npm is linking the correct directory.

Comment: Sadly not. I opened a feature request within the npm GitHub repo however. One of the comments points out a possible solution, but personally I find it to be too complicated... You can check it out here: github.com/npm/cli/issues/6614#issuecomment-1848259077

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I totally agree with you.